# How to split a field within Python and return value in another column?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, csv, split

I have an csv containing data like the below:

```
"A17W-1000010931-RED-14"
```

I am trying to split the data by the 3rd hyphen so that it returns everything before it, like below:

```
"A17W-1000010931-RED"
```

This is most likely an easy task but i am struggling to find an answer.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your data in a pandas DataFrame?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `.replace`:

```
df["your column"] = df["your column"].replace(
    r"(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-.*", "\\1-\\2-\\3", regex=True
)
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of generic string manipulation methods for Python. Probably pandas has something better.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("^[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*", "A17W-1000010931-RED-14")[0]
'A17W-1000010931-RED'
```

Another way:

```
>>> "-".join("A17W-1000010931-RED-14".split("-")[:3])
'A17W-1000010931-RED'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
string= "A17W-1000010931-RED-14"
es=string.split("-")[:3]
jes='-'.join(es)
merge='"'+jes+'"'
```

If your print merge it would show you the output of your desired result

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your column is a `pandas.Series` object named `series`

```
series = pd.Series(["A17W-1000010931-RED-14", 'ABC-123-COLOR-Other-Stuff'] * 2)
series

0       A17W-1000010931-RED-14
1    ABC-123-COLOR-Other-Stuff
2       A17W-1000010931-RED-14
3    ABC-123-COLOR-Other-Stuff
dtype: object
```

#### `str.find`, string slicing, and `list` comprehension

```
[x[:x.find('-', x.find('-', x.find('-') + 1) + 1)] for x in series]

['A17W-1000010931-RED',
 'ABC-123-COLOR',
 'A17W-1000010931-RED',
 'ABC-123-COLOR']
```

---

#### Details

I'm attempting to minimize the creation of new objects.

- Finds the first position of a `'-'` and adds one to it

  ```
  x.find('-') + 1
  ```
- We can pass a starting position to `str.find` so that it only searches past a certain point... like where the first `'-'` is.  But the above is exactly the starting point in which I'd like to begin searching for the second `'-'`

  ```
  x.find('-', x.find('-') + 1) + 1
  ```
- Repeat the process to find the third

  ```
  x.find('-', x.find('-', x.find('-') + 1) + 1)
  ```
- Now that I have the position, we can slice the string easily

  ```
  x[:x.find('-', x.find('-', x.find('-') + 1) + 1)]
  ```

---

An alternative way would be to `str.split` and `str.join`

```
# Note that I limit this to 3 splits with this
#                      ↓
['-'.join(x.split('-', 3)[:3]) for x in series]
```

Which is fine.